# JSON Data types passed through an API

Tags: json, api

In a JSON formatted file there are 8 data types that I am aware of.

1. Number
2. String
3. Boolean
4. Array
5. Value
6. Object
7. Whitespace
8. Null

I know in a JSON formatted file numeric values do not need double quotes and strings do. My question is when data is sent using any API how do the data types get parsed. If you send a Boolean in quotes does that get interpreted as a string or a Boolean and more specific does a Boolean of 0 or 1 get processed as a numeric value and T or F a string? The same would go for Whitespace and Null would the Whitespace get processed as a empty string and a null just pass as a null string.

Comment: Value? what is this?

Comment: Value

it can be a string, a number, true or false, null etc I received the data types list from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm

Comment: And Whitespace is string " "?

Answer (score 1):

In all JSON APIs, `false` and `true` are parsed as booleans, 0 and 1 as numbers, `null` as null, " " and "" as a strings.

Now when trying to map the data to an existing class, some framework may take the liberty to provide automatic conversions from one type to another, but I wouldn't count on it.

Also, you can sometimes customise the mapping to a class and do whatever you want.

To summarise, it all depends on the framework your using.